# What is exactly in an Android rom.zip

Tags: android, linux, android-ndk, rom

I want to ask that what's the structure of a zip format Android Rom. I have unziped some of them. But I couldn't figure out how the boot loader flash install them on the mobile. Anyone could tell me what exactly the boot loader do?

I am familiar with Linux. So I want to know some low level things. I wonder if I could cross compile the Linux kernel and some Linux's tools(like [CLFS project](http://trac.cross-lfs.org/)) and install them on the mobile.

Anyone has some hint? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends from the updater-script.
If there is a `boot.img` (kernel+ramdisk), with the raw command, the `boot.img` will be flash on boot partition.
All the other folder will be flash on system partition.
You should watch an updater-script which is in `META-INF/com/google/android` or something like that.